# Autosize для textarea не работает в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Использую `bootstrap3` и стороннюю библиотеку [autosize textarea by Jack Moore](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/).

У меня есть модальное окно, в котором находится `textarea` и этот `textarea` при открытии модального окна не подгоняется под размер текста в нем. Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
 <!-- <script src="https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize/blob/master/dist/autosize.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jackmoore/autosize/master/dist/autosize.js"></script>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="40%">
          <label class="left-cell">Наименование, здания (сооружения) в соответствии с проектной документацией, адрес объекта</label>
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
          <textarea class="form-control readonly" asp-for="@Model.EtpDocTitleP1s.Value" readonly id="TitleP1">Этот textarea растягивается сразу при загрузке страницы.</textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!--Модальнео окно-->
  <div id="mTitleP1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form asp-action="SetTitleP1" asp-controller="ETP">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.EtpDocTitleP1s.EtpDocTitleP1id" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.EtpDocTitleP1s.EtpMainId" />
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td width="40%">
                    <label class="left-cell">Наименование, здания (сооружения) в соответствии с проектной документацией, адрес объекта</label>
                  </td>
                  <td width="60%">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="mta">А этот textarea растягивается, только если в него что-то ввести.</textarea>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <input type="submit" value="Сохранить изменения" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <style>
    textarea {
      overflow: hidden;
      /*прокрутка*/
      resize: none;
      /*угололк*/
      -ms-overflow-style: none;
      /*для IE прокрутка*/
    }
    
    textarea.readonly {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
  <!--autosize-textarea-->
  <script>
    autosize(document.querySelectorAll('textarea'));
  </script>
  <!--вызов модального окна-->
  <script>
    $('#TitleP1').click(function() {
      $('#mTitleP1').modal('show');
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Подключите нормально скрипт autosize.js
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jackmoore/autosize/master/dist/autosize.js

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/256316)

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin как раз это и есть ответ на вопрос - "почему не работает?", а не внесение уточнений. Я бы вам для начало посоветовал, прежде чем утверждать, потестить данный код, пройти по ссылкам подключения скриптов и т. п.